# Preventing variable width when using plot_implicit

Tags: python, plot, sympy

Plotting equation `(y-x**2)**2 = x**5` with:

```
from sympy import init_printing, plot_implicit, symbols, Eq

init_printing()
x, y = symbols('x y', real=True)
eq = Eq((y-x**2)**2, x**5)
plot_implicit(eq, (x,0,1), (y,0,.2))
```

Gives:

[image]

The curve should be of constant width. What is the reason for the varying width? how can it be improved?

I tried using `adaptive=False`, the width is more constant at the cost of a terrible aliasing, and no longer passing through the origin:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `adaptive=False` you can set the number of discretization points used by the algorithm:

```
plot_implicit(eq, (x,0,1), (y,0,.2), adaptive=False, points=4000)
```

Do not increase that number too much: watch out your system monitor as it will use a lot of memory!

Comment: There is an improvement on certain aspects, the curve meets the origin. As you warned RAM is solicited and process time increases.